# android apk publish with the web service

Tags: android, web-services, google-play, restful-url

I made an `android application` with `Restful` web service.
my question is can i upload the web service with the `APK` to google play if not what is the cheapest way to make my web service up and running ?

Comment: Your app doesn't contain a web service... It simply connects to one. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You've to buy domain and host your web-service files. cheers

Comment: @cricket_007 i know that my app does not contain a web service :)  but it use one

Comment: I am not web developer but if you looking for cheap hosting maybe godaddy be nice choice for you , then change all url of web service according to your new domain

Comment: @Aks4125 that's mean google play does not host services

Comment: Then nothing is different between testing your app and publishing your app unless your Web service has just been your local computer

Comment: What you need is a virtual private server (VPS), however recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that's the problem my web service is not online it's a localhost and i am looking for the cheapest way to make it online

Answer (score 0):

No you have to host your APIs separately. Probably on amazon web services (aws) or [google cloud](https://cloud.google.com). There are many other providers. Just search and you'll get several options.

Register for [aws free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) if traffic is not going to be huge to test it out.

On google play store you will be publishing just the apk. And that apk should be pre configuration to access your APIs from where ever you choose to host them.

Comment: can you explain a little bit about the steps of using google cloud or refer to a tutorial please.

Comment: Updated answer with links